# getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when creating images(thumbnails/images) from pdfFile using PDFRender API 

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, out-of-memory

I am working on project where I need to creating PDFImags from PdfFile, for that i am using PDFRendere API. my program running successfully when Pdf File Size is small like 104 kb, 180 kb, 421 kb etc, but I am getting **"Exception in thread "Image Fetcher 0" **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space***
"* when PdfFile size approx  or more then 12 mb, 13 mb, 20 mb.
I check it on windows XP, windows2003 server, and on linux OS and And also increase java heap size approx 1024 mb but I am still getting   **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**.
My code is as

```
    try {

        pdfFileName = pdfFileName.trim();
        if (pdfFileName != null || !(pdfFileName.equals(""))) {
            lastIndexx = pdfFileName.lastIndexOf('.');

            if (lastIndexx < 0) // if extension not present, concatenate the extension
            {
                filePath = pdfPath+ pdfFileName + ".pdf";

            } else {
                filePath = pdfPath+ pdfFileName;
                pdfFileName = pdfFileName.substring(0, lastIndexx);
            }
            System.out.println("Pdf system's  redefine physical path, where pdfFile are stored, from PdfController.java : " +filePath);
            file = new File(filePath);
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            channel = raf.getChannel();
            byteBuf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
            System.out.println("PdfFile Name before Trim() :" + pdfFileName + ":");
            // get a pdf file when pdf is password protected.
            byte[] bytePassword = pdfFileName.trim()).getBytes();               
            pdfPassword = new PDFPassword(bytePassword); 
            pdffile = new PDFFile(byteBuf, pdfPassword);

            // draw the image of particular page
            dpage = pdffile.getPage(pageNo);              

            //get the width and height for the doc at the default zoom
            rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) dpage.getBBox().getWidth(), (int) dpage.getBBox().getHeight());
            //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0, 200, 300);

            //BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(rect.width, rect.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);                
            //generate the image
            img = dpage.getImage(
                    //rect.width, rect.height, //width & height
                    width, height,                 // hardcoded in jsp
                    rect, // clip rect
                    null, // null for the ImageObserver
                    true, // fill background with white
                    true // block until drawing is done
                    );                
            bufImageGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();                
            bufImageGraphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null); 
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File(directoryName + "//" + pdfFileName + "_" + pageNo + ".jpg"));
                    succ = true;

    } /*catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        System.out.println("From showPdfMetaData.jsp, OutOfMemoryError, Message : " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("From showPdfMetaData.jsp, OutOfMemoryError, Message : " + ex.getCause());
        //errorType = "Jvm throw OutOfMemoryError";
   }*/catch (MethodNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("From pdfToImage(), MethodNotFoundException, Message : " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("From pdfToImage(), MethodNotFoundException, Message : " + ex.getCause());
        System.out.println("pdfFileName, from pdfToImage(), MethodNotFoundException: " + pdfFileName);
        succ = false;
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("from pdfToImage(), StringIndexOutOfBoundsException !!!");
        System.out.println("pdfFileName, from pdfToImage(), StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + pdfFileName);
        e.printStackTrace();
        succ = false;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("from pdfToImage(), FileNotFoundException !!!");
        System.out.println("pdfFileName, from pdfToImage(), FileNotFoundException: " + pdfFileName);
        e.printStackTrace();
        succ = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("from pdfToImage(), IOException !!!");
        System.out.println("pdfFileName, from pdfToImage(), IOException: " + pdfFileName);
        e.printStackTrace();
        succ = false;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("from pdfToImage(), NullPointerException !!!");
        System.out.println("pdfFileName, from pdfToImage(), NullPointerException: " + pdfFileName);
        e.printStackTrace();
        succ = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("from pdfToImage(), General Exception !!!");
        System.out.println("pdfFileName, from pdfToImage(), Exception: " + pdfFileName);
        e.printStackTrace();
        succ = false;
    } finally {
        if (raf != null) {                
            byteBuf.clear();
            channel.close();
            raf.close();
        }
        if(bufferedImage !=null){
           bufferedImage.flush();
           //bufImageGraphics.finalize();
        }
        if(bufImageGraphics !=null){
           bufImageGraphics.dispose();
        }
        if(pdfPassword !=null){
           pdfPassword = null;               
        }            
        if(dpage !=null){
           dpage = null;
        }
        if(rect !=null){
           rect = null;
        }if(img !=null){
            img.flush();
           img = null;
        }if(dmsMgmt !=null){
           dmsMgmt = null;
        }
    }
    return succ;
}
```

when i debug program it throw out of memory error at

```
img = dpage.getImage(
                    //rect.width, rect.height, //width & height
                    width, height,
                    rect, // clip rect
                    null, // null for the ImageObserver
                    true, // fill background with white
                    true // block until drawing is done
                    );
```

I am calling this method from jsp. So please guid me any poissible suggestion.
Thanks in advance, I am sorry for any wrong cause as it my first question here...I will try not repeat if am asking qustion wrong way

Comment: I recommend you use JConsole to check on your JVM's memory allocation, and see if you are not leaking objects in some way. It could be because your code doesn't make it easy enough for GC to retrieve space, a bug in the VM, or maybe you're just asking for too much...

Comment: Thanks for so fast replies, but as clearly i don't know about JConsole and how to use it, but  I will try to us it by reading about it. but if any other solution then most welcome and thanks..

Comment: Yep, definitely best for you to read about JConsole - it's a great tool, but explaining you here would take a community wiki :)

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 possible reasons for java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

1. Your application just needs more memory that you provide it. You can try to increase the memory allocation for it using -Xmx parameter to the java. E.g. try add -Xmx512m to your java command line.
2. Your application or one the libraries that you use [leaks memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Then you need to try one of the many tools available to find out and fix the cause of this leak. You can recommend [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu), the new player in the field.

Comment: **@Nikem** firstly I Thanks to you for replies, but as I already mention that I increases my JVM size up-to 1024 mb and i also tried  with 2048 mb, but I as still getting same error. As i start my application, I do some search from database after that i click to create a image from searched PdfFile, but it failed as it through out of memory error....And for second suggestion i don't know how to use **Plumbr** but i will try it if success............please give me any more suggestion....Thanks to you...

Comment: is there any alternate way to create pdf image/thumbnails from pdfFile, as i still not able find required solution of this above error.

Comment: @ArvindGangwar, did you try running jconsole? what were your observations in it?

Comment: @aishwarya, Yha i try it, but unable to how to monitor my application with **jconsole**. I run jconsole from command prompt as C:/jconsole without any parameter and select sun.tools.jconsole. Jconsole......Please guid me how to use jconsole to monitor my application

Comment: @ArvindGangwar, please refer to [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html)